# Pagination of a dynamically generated html purely with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a html table in which rows are dynamically generated. I want to implement pagination to this table based on css and javascript/jquery.

below is the code for the table:

```js
< script >
 var loop_var = 0;

function select_taf() {
 if (loop_var == 0) {
  loop_var = 1;
  $("table.order-list tbody").empty();
  var name1 = "<%= Request.Cookies["emailid"].Value.ToString() %>";
  var dtt = document.getElementById("year_date").value;
  var tafid;
  if (document.getElementById("open_taf").value == "") {
   $("table.order-list1 tbody").empty();
   $("table.order-list tbody").empty();
   tafid = 0;
   var myObj;
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.overrideMimeType("application/json");
   request.open("GET", '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverip1"].ToString() %>' + name1 + "/" + tafid + "/" + dtt);
   request.send();
   request.onload = function() {
    var superHero = request.response;
    myObj = JSON.parse(superHero);
    myObj = JSON.parse(myObj);
    for (i in myObj.open_list) {
     check3(i, myObj.open_list[i].taf_no, myObj.open_list[i].purpose, myObj.open_list[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.open_list[i].no_of_days, myObj.open_list[i].adv_amt, myObj.open_list[i].remarks, myObj.open_list[i].tid, name1, dtt);
    }
    for (i in myObj.await_app) {
     check4(i, myObj.await_app[i].tid, myObj.await_app[i].purpose, myObj.await_app[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.await_app[i].no_of_days, myObj.await_app[i].adv_amt, myObj.await_app[i].remarks, "Await Manager Approval", myObj.await_app[i].yot);
    }
    for (i in myObj.manager_2_await) {
     check4(i, myObj.manager_2_await[i].tid, myObj.manager_2_await[i].purpose, myObj.manager_2_await[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.manager_2_await[i].no_of_days, myObj.manager_2_await[i].adv_amt, myObj.manager_2_await[i].remarks, "Await Manager 2 Approval", myObj.manager_2_await[i].yot);
    }
    for (i in myObj.manager_1_reject) {
     check4(i, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].tid, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].purpose, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].no_of_days, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].adv_amt, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].remarks, "Manager 1 Reject", myObj.manager_1_reject[i].yot);
    }
    for (i in myObj.manager_2_reject) {
     check4(i, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].tid, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].purpose, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].no_of_days, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].adv_amt, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].remarks, 'Manager 2 Reject', myObj.manager_2_reject[i].yot);
    }
    for (i in myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1) {
     check4(i, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].tid, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].purpose, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].no_of_days, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].adv_amt, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].remarks, 'Auto-Approved by manager 1', myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].yot);
    }
    loop_var = 0;
   }
  } else {
   $("table.order-list tbody").empty();
   $("table.order-list1 tbody").empty();
   tafid = document.getElementById("open_taf").value;
   var myObj;
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.overrideMimeType("application/json");
   request.open("GET", '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverip1"].ToString() %>' + name1 + "/" + tafid + "/" + dtt);
   request.send();
   request.onload = function() {
    var superHero = request.response;
    myObj = JSON.parse(superHero);
    myObj = JSON.parse(myObj);
    //var counter = myObj.count;
    //alert(counter);
    for (i in myObj.open_list) {
     check3(i, myObj.open_list[i].taf_no, myObj.open_list[i].purpose, myObj.open_list[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.open_list[i].no_of_days, myObj.open_list[i].adv_amt, myObj.open_list[i].remarks, myObj.open_list[i].tid, name1, dtt);
    }
    for (i in myObj.await_app) {
     check4(i, myObj.await_app[i].tid, myObj.await_app[i].purpose, myObj.await_app[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.await_app[i].no_of_days, myObj.await_app[i].adv_amt, myObj.await_app[i].remarks, "Await Manager Approval", myObj.await_app[i].yot);
    }
    for (i in myObj.manager_2_await) {
     check4(i, myObj.manager_2_await[i].tid, myObj.manager_2_await[i].purpose, myObj.manager_2_await[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.manager_2_await[i].no_of_days, myObj.manager_2_await[i].adv_amt, myObj.manager_2_await[i].remarks, "Await Manager 2 Approval", myObj.manager_2_await[i].yot);
    }
    for (i in myObj.manager_1_reject) {
     check4(i, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].tid, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].purpose, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].no_of_days, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].adv_amt, myObj.manager_1_reject[i].remarks, "Manager 1 Reject", myObj.manager_1_reject[i].yot);
    }
    for (i in myObj.manager_2_reject) {
     check4(i, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].tid, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].purpose, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].no_of_days, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].adv_amt, myObj.manager_2_reject[i].remarks, 'Manager 2 Reject', myObj.manager_2_reject[i].yot);
    }
    for (i in myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1) {
     check4(i, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].tid, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].purpose, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].loc_of_vst, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].no_of_days, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].adv_amt, myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].remarks, 'Auto-Approved by manager 1', myObj.Auto_app_mrg_1[i].yot);
    }
    loop_var = 0;
   }
  }
 }
}

function check4(counter, data, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7) {
 var newRow = $("<tr>");
 var cols = "";
 cols += '<td name="name' + counter + '">' + data + '</td>';
 cols += '<td name="from_loc' + counter + '">' + data1 + '</td>';
 cols += '<td name="to_loc' + counter + '">' + data2 + '</td>';
 cols += '<td name="date_of_travel' + counter + '">' + data3 + '</td>';
 cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '">' + data4 + '</td>';
 cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '">' + data5 + '</td>';
 if (data6 === "Await Manager Approval") {
  cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '"> Approval Pending </td>';
  cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '"> Approval Pending </td>';
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" id="' + data + "_" + data7 + '" onclick="shw_taf(this.id)">Detail</button></td>';
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" id="' + data + "_" + data7 + '" onclick="edt_taf(this.id)">Delete</button></td>';
 } else if (data6 === "Auto-Approved by manager 1") {
  cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '">Auto-Approved </td>';
  cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '"> Approval Pending </td>';
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" id="' + data + "_" + data7 + '" onclick="shw_taf(this.id)">Detail</button></td>';
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" id="' + data + "_" + data7 + '" onclick="edt_taf(this.id)">Delete</button></td>';
 } else if (data6 === "Await Manager 2 Approval") {
  cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '"> Approved </td>';
  cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '"> Approval Pending </td>';
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" id="' + data + "_" + data7 + '" onclick="shw_taf(this.id)">Detail</button></td>';
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" id="' + data + "_" + data7 + '" onclick="edt_taf(this.id)">Delete</button></td>';
 } else if (data6 === "Manager 1 Reject") {
  cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '"> Request Denied </td>';
  cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '"> Not Required </td>';
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" id="' + data + "_" + data7 + '" onclick="shw_taf(this.id)">Detail</button></td>';
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" id="' + data + "_" + data7 + '" onclick="edt_taf(this.id)">Delete</button></td>';
 } else if (data6 === "Manager 2 Reject") {
  cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '"> Approved </td>';
  cols += '<td name="status' + counter + '"> Request Denied </td>';
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" id="' + data + "_" + data7 + '" onclick="shw_taf(this.id)">Detail</button></td>';
  cols += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" id="' + data + "_" + data7 + '" onclick="edt_taf(this.id)">Delete</button></td>';
 }
 newRow.append(cols);
 $("table.order-list1").append(newRow);
} <
/script>
```

I have tried data tables that are not working for my project and other few methods given here on StackOverflow.

Please guide regarding this

Comment: it would be useful to add some comments in the code so it's more readable. also, please fix the indentation. lastly, since there's so much nesting, consider indenting with two spaces instead of four. once we're able to read and understand the code, we might be able to help.

Comment: please check now I updated according to suggested edit. Major idea is that in check4 function the rows are being created. Please check once more if it understandable now

Comment: @Ganesa Vijayakumar thank you for the edit.

Comment: there is a reason behind the choice to do the table on your own, instead of using some jquery table library (like [datatables](https://datatables.net/))?

You have a lot of built-in to handle paginations, rendering etc

Comment: @Margon yes correct. Is their a way to put pagination also. Datatables didn't work I found that online and tried using it. Table structure I cannot change because to many functions running based on requirement. Any method of implementing it via CSS and javascript.